# Filter a list by a value in a User's profile

Tags: jquery, spservices

I would like to replace the functionality of the Current User Filter of SharePoint Server 2010 enterprise.  I think I might be able to use SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser but I am unsure if it is possilbe.  I hope to populate a hidden text box and filter via that value but I am unsure if I can do it asynchronously or if it is possible at all.  Does anyone have insight for me?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by _replace the functionality of the Current User Filter_

Comment: In the Enterprise version, there is a Web Part named 'Current User Filter'.  It enables filtering a connected web part by the current user's login name or the current user's value of a selected profile property.  Unfortunately,  I cannot use Enterprise functionality in this implementation.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-filter-web-parts-HA010033786.aspx#BM2

Comment: what have you tried?  Have you tried to call SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser, and does it return the value you are looking for?  If not you'll probably need to call the user profile service to fetch the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a Web Part instead of trying to build a solution with SPServices.